# Запрет повторной отправки формы при переходах по истории браузера

Tags: php

Для запрета повторного отправления формы при перезагрузке страницы я помещаю в форму скрытое поле с rand(). Обработчик формы сверяет полученный rand() с уже имеющейся сессионной переменной, хранящей rand() предыдущего запроса. С случае совпадения форма не обрабатывается. Это все работает. Однако если страницу не перезагружать, а просто понажимать кнопки "назад" и "вперед", то форма обработается сколько угодно раз. Как бы этого избежать? Может быть нужно пойти другим путем?

Comment: Вы же форму `post`'ом отправляете?

Comment: Сделайте отправку данных ajax'ом — это свежо, модно и спортивно! )

Comment: Ajaxом делается, чтоб было красивее, свежо, модно и спортивно, а не потому что это невозможно сделать  классическим методом. Поэтому интересует вопрос по php.

Comment: Это была шутка. На комментарии к вопросу ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: 1. Да, постом.
2. Меняю ключ сессии на случайное  число, заданное в скрытом поле формы.

Comment: Алгоритм с ключем:

1. сгенерировали ключ;

2. записали его в сессию;

3. выдали форму с этим ключем в `input type="hidden"`;

4. приняли данные от пользователя, сверили ключ с ключем в сессии, сменили ключ сессии.

Теперь если он back/forward его спросит "переслать ли еще раз post-данные? - Даже, если скажет "Да", они перешлются со старым ключем, который не позволит сохранить данные повторно.

У вас не так?

Comment: Ага, по-ходу я этот алгоритм отбросил, у вас СРАЗУ задается сессионный ключ, а затем записывается в поле формы, у меня же на данный момент - наоборот.

Comment: @sergiks,большое спасибо. Странно, что у меня была проверка на НЕРАВЕНСТВО

Comment: ой, сорвалось, изменил код как вы подсказали - все ок! Переходим на аджакс! )))

Comment: Возможно, это поможет: header("Location: http://host.tld")

Comment: @den, после моего вопроса прошло уже 2 года))) Конечно же я, после получения данных формы, использую header('location:...')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так будет правильнее

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache,mustrevalidate");
header("Location: http://host.tld");
```

Comment: Вместо размещения второго ответа, исправляющего первый, имеет смысл отредактировать первый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Imgur]

Данная проблема уже давно (со времен более ранних, чем 2013 год) бороздит интернет. По умолчанию обновление страницы во всех браузерах заставит повторить запрос, а если страница была загружена POST-запросом, то данные загрузятся снова. Забытая вкладка могла запускать веб-приложение при каждом открытии браузера. Переход по истории вперед-назад может ровно так же запустить что-то неприятное, чего хотелось бы избежать.

У данной проблемы есть одно общепринятое крепкое решение - паттерн Post-Redirect-Get. Он подразумевает, что после отправки формы клиенту будет отдан ответ перенаправления на результирующую страницу (возможно, ту же самую), которая будет получена через GET-запрос. Таким образом убиваются сразу несколько лебедей разом:

- Из-за перенаправления со статусом 302 или аналогичным страница не запишется в историю
- При обновлении результирующей страницы пользователь повторно отправит GET-запрос, у него не будет возможности повторить POST-запрос до тех пор, пока он не повторит ручной ввод формы

**Почему я считаю, что аякс - это не решение**

Потому что, несмотря на уничтожение тех же препятствий, он вносит в приложение неконсистентность. Если вам не пришло в голову сразу это сделать аяксом, то, вероятно, он не используется для этого в приложении, и таким образом просто открывается еще одна сфера приложения, которую нужно тестировать, поддерживать и расширять; при любом повторении сценария надо будет писать общий механизм, к которому наверняка сразу не получится придумать правильный интерфейс, а значит при любом чихе придется переписывать все места, где он используется, в общем, ну его, если вы не видите четко весь механизм работы приложения.

**Что мне делать с данными, которые мне надо показать единожды на результирующей странице?**

Для этого потребуется сессия и еще один паттерн - Flash Attributes, параметры, которые удаляются из сессии после их прочтения, т.е. сообщения, которые можно прочитать максимум один раз. То есть для передачи этих данных после успешного срабатывания формы надо их передать в сессии, а на результирующей странице - прочитать и стереть. Может выглядеть сложно, но на самом деле ничего сложного тут нет, этот механизм используется везде, и все ему рады. И, конечно, он уже зашит в любой фреймворк.

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать при отправки формы проверять, есть ли такие данные, т.е были уже отправлены, такой вариант не устроит?

Comment: Тоже так думал, но боюсь, что сканировать ради этого всю таблицу - не вариант. Есть же какая-то фишка для этого все-таки.

Comment: А если так реализовать, при первой отправки в сессию записать имя формы со значение true. После второй отправки, делать проверку на сессию. П.с не забудьте поткл. сессию)

Comment: Я ж вопрос и задал по этому поводу. у меня в форме ренерируется случайное число, оно и заноситься в сессию. Все работает, если жать F5 - форма не будет повторно отправляться. Но если нажать "назад" в браузере - генеригуется новое число - и форма отправляется!

Comment: Я уточнил, что именно название формы должно быть ключем сессии. Так, оно должно сработать. Проверьте ;-)

Comment: )) У меня у формы и имени-то нет.

Comment: К тому же если я захочу еще раз отправить форму с другими данными - у мне не выйдет - имя сессии совпадет с именем формы.)) А у меня добавление комментариев!))

Comment: Тогда можно поступить иначе)):  
1. При добавление запроса, указать что запрещать дубликат данных;  
2. Сделать проверку на дубликат до занесение в БД;  
3. Добавить значение сессии как текст комментария ;-) ;
4. При отправке в сессию поместить время и после второй отправки смотреть ( не очень вариант));
5. Сделать Капчу) ( Например 2+2);
6. Написать на яваскрипте скрипт, какой будет очищать поля после нажатия назад.

Comment: Можно в сессию записать мд5 от отправленных даанных. и потом перед отпраавкой проверить без сканирование таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Привет, столкнулся был стакой самой проблемой. Решил Все очень просто.
Записал в сесию число `$_SESSION['orderrang'] = "1";` и потом после отправки проверяю сесию, если равна `1` то делаю все необходимие мне действия и вконце изменяю ее значение на другое. Таким образом пры повторной отправки `$_SESSION['orderrang']` уже не равно 1

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не хватает файла капчи и файла функций задействованных в скрипте но сути это не меняет. Форма полностью рабочая, со всеми проверками, если кому надо вот ссылка на недостоющие файлы https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Tba/Wn4BQvmSf

А тут пример скрипта http://maxmusicmax.ru/form/

```
<?php
session_start ();
include ('/form_func.php');
if (!isset ($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = 'Введите Ваше сообщение:<hr>';
}
//unset ($_SESSION['errors']);
// Если нажата кнопка «Отправить сообщение»
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))  {
    $yourname = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['yourname']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['message']);
    $_SESSION['yourname'] = $yourname;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    $for_you = $_POST['for_you']; // Скрытое поле (дополнительная проверка)
    $redir = '/form3.php';
    $errors = array (); // Массив ошибок
    // Проверка поля «for_you»
    if ($for_you !== '') {
        unset ($_POST['yourname']);
        unset ($_POST['email']);
        unset ($_POST['message']);
        unset ($_POST['submit']);
    }
    // Проверка поля «Введите Ваше имя:»
    if (does_it_exist ($yourname)) {
        $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Введите Ваше имя</p><hr></div>';
        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    } else {
        if (preg_match ('/  /', $yourname)) {
            $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Двойной пробел в имени не допустим</p><hr></div>';
            header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
    }
    // Проверка поля «Введите Ваш Email:»
    if ($email == '') {
        $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Введите Ваш Email</p><hr></div>';
        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    } else {
        if (preg_match ('/ /', $email)) {
            $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Пробелы в Email-е не допустимы</p><hr></div>';
            header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
        if (!preg_match ('/^((([0-9A-Za-z]{1}[-0-9A-z\.]{1,}[0-9A-Za-z]{1})|([0-9А-Яа-я]{1}[-0-9А-я\.]{1,}[0-9А-Яа-я]{1}))@([-0-9A-Za-z]{1,}\.){1,2}[-A-Za-z]{2,})$/u', $email)) {
            $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Введите корректный Email</p><hr></div>';
            header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
    }
    // Проверка поля «Введите сообщение:»
    if (does_it_exist ($message)) {
        $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Введите сообщение</p><hr></div>';
        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    // Проверка капчи
    if ($_POST['secpic'] == '') {
        $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Введите цифры</p><hr></div>';
        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    } else {
        if ($_SESSION['secpic'] !== $_POST['secpic']) {
            $errors[] = '<div class="errors"><p>Цифры введены не верно</p><hr></div>';
            header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
    }
    // Отправляем форму
    if (empty ($errors) && $_SESSION['secpic'] == $_POST['secpic'] && $for_you == '') {
        //$errors[] = '<div class="sent_successfully"><p>Отправлено !!!</p></div>';
        //$_SESSION['errors'] = array_shift ($errors);
        unset ($_SESSION['errors']);
        unset ($_SESSION['yourname']);
        unset ($_SESSION['email']);
        unset ($_SESSION['message']);
        unset ($_SESSION['submit']);
        unset ($_POST['yourname']);
        unset ($_POST['email']);
        unset ($_POST['message']);
        unset ($_POST['submit']);
        if (strpos ($redir, 'mail=1') === false) {
                $redir .= '?mail=1';
            }
        header ('Location: ' . $redir);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = array_shift ($errors);
        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru-ru" lang="ru-ru" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Форма</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.errors {
color: #ff0000;
font-weight: bold;
}
.sent_successfully {
color: #008c00;
font-weight: bold;
}
.hidden_form {
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<?php
if (isset ($_GET['mail']) == 1) {
    echo '<p>Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="form3.php">Написать ещё сообщение</a></p>';
    $hidden_form = ' class="hidden_form"';
} else {
    //echo 'Введите Ваше сообщение<hr>';
    $hidden_form = '';
    if (isset ($_SESSION['errors'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['errors'];
    }
}
?>
<form action="form3.php" method="post" <?php echo $hidden_form; ?>>
<input type="text" name="for_you" value="" size="" style="display: none;" />
<label>Введите Ваше имя:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="yourname" value="<?php echo @$_SESSION['yourname']; ?>" size="" /><br>
<label>Введите Ваш Email:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo @$_SESSION['email']; ?>" size="" /><br>
<label>Введите сообщение:</label><br>
<textarea name="message" value="" cols="" rows=""><?php echo @$_SESSION['message']; ?></textarea><br>

<span class="errors"></span><br />
<input type="text" name="secpic" /><br />
<div style="border: 1px solid #000000;display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;"><img src="secpic.php?" id="secpic" title="Обновить картинку" onClick="this.src = 'secpic.php?'+Math.random();"/></div><br />
<span onclick="document.getElementById('secpic').src = 'secpic.php?' + Math.random()" style="cursor: pointer;">Обновить картинку</span><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Отправить сообщение" />
</form><br>
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<?php
echo ('<hr> ');
echo ('<b>POST:</b> ');
var_dump ($_POST);
echo ('<hr> ');
echo '<b>SESSION:</b> ';
var_dump ($_SESSION);
echo ('<hr> ');
?>
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<a href="form3.php">form3.php</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Много задействовано сессионных переменных. Обошелся абсолютно без них. Форма отправляется пхп-скрипту. Скрипт заносит все полученные данные в массив, в случае ошибки пользователя весь этот массив отправляется "обратно" и выводится в соответствующих полях формы. Ни одной сессионной переменной не задействовано, (кроме скрытой переменной с рандомным числом). Как вы потом - после отправки формы - собираетесь удалять переменные сессии, которые будут продолжать "нагружать" сервер?

Comment: @Deus, вы бы свой ответ качественно оформили и потом принял как верный, раз ни один из текущих вас не устроил.

Comment: unset — Удаляет переменную
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php